# How to fire Blur event to window with javascript

Tags: javascript

I set a text in a field with javascript, then I send change event to that field.
I would like to fire blur event on the window as the website require.

to set the text in the input field I use `"document.getElementsByTagName('input')[23].value = 'London'"`

to send change event to the input field I use

```
var o = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[23]; 
    if (document.createEvent) { 
            var evt = document.createEvent('Events'); 
            evt.initEvent('change', true, true); 
            o.dispatchEvent(evt); }
```

now I would like to send blur event but to window, I don t know how to do that.

this is the source code for the field :

```
<span class="next-input next-error next-large address-input">
 <input height="100%" autocomplete="off" value="" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0s.8850659.0.i9.2bdb6c37UwO8uq"></span>
```

this is the process that the website do :

```
change Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: input, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 3, …}



 blur 
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "blur", target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: [Window]
returnValue: true
srcElement: Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
target: Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
timeStamp: 30631177.38000001
type: "blur"
__proto__: Event
```

Comment: Do you really need to fire an event or do you just need to call the code that that event handler would normally call? If so, just manually call the handler. And, if you do need to fire the event, just call it (i.e. `someElement.blur()`)

Comment: I think call the code, for change I use document.getElementsByTagName but for blur if I replace change by blur it doesn't work, it erase and put back the previous text or blanc. I though maybe it s because I need it send to the window instead to the "input"?